# Repeated timing of a void function in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, void-pointers, benchmarking

I am trying to time a void function

```c
for (size_t round = 0; round < 5; round++) {
    cpu_time_start = get_cpu_time();
    wall_time_start = get_wall_time();

    scan.assign_clusters(epsilon, mu);

    cpu_time_end = get_cpu_time();
    wall_time_end = get_wall_time();
    ...
}
```

The first timing yields 300 seconds, while the next four timings yields 0.000002 seconds. This indicates that the void function call to `assign_clusters` is optimized out. How can I force my program to execute this time consuming function call every time, and yet still use optimization for the rest of the code?

What I usually do is to save the result of the function in question and then print it, but since this is a `void` function, do I have the same option?

I use the following optimization flags: `-std=c++0x -march=native -O2`

Comment: It could also be a cache effect. or a better branch prediction in the subsequent runs.

Comment: Are you sure `assign_clusters` is optimized out? Did you take a look at the assembly code? Without knowing what `assign_clusters` does this is hard to answer. Maybe this function is so fast the second time because your system just does not need to assign the clusters twice.

Comment: What happens if you compile your code _without_ any optimisation?

Comment: @flowit you were right! Being taught that the compiler was clever, I thought that this was the issue. To use a Danish technical phrase: This was an error 40 (An error occurred 40 cm from the screen). I oblivious forgot to call my reset function. Thanks for the second pair of eyes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is taking the time, to make the fix.

This could be caused by :-

1. Loading services.  Your clustering may be database based, and requires the database services to start (the first time)
2. Disk caching.  The OS will remember data it has read, and be able to provide the data as if it was in memory.
3. Memory caching.  The CPU has different speeds of memory available to it, using the same memory twice, would be faster the second time.
4. State caching. The data may be in a more amenable state for subsequent runs.  This can be thought of as sorting an array twice.  The second time is already sorted, which can produce a speed up.

Service starting can be a number of seconds.

Disk cache approx 20x speed up.
Memory cache approx 6x speed up
State caching, can be unbounded.

I think your code needs to reset the scan object, to ensure it does the work again

Comment: As flowit pointed out in the comments of the question, you are also right. The scan object was not reset. However, I will also look at the memory caching issue, since the first is a tat slower than the next calls.